# For a compact metric space $X ,f: X \rightarrow X $ s.t $ d(x,y)\leq d(f(x),f(y))$ is surjective

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I want to show that in a compact metrix space $X$ ,the function $f :X \to X$ such that $d(x,y) \le d(f(x),f(y))$ is surjective!
I tried to show that f is continuous and injective but i don't think it really have to...

Comment: Wait, you don't assume it's continuous?

Comment: No it's not Necessarily continuous! :-(

Comment: I'm amazed to see a close vote for such a nice question.

Comment: @RobArthan I'm amazed to see it's not already closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @404: I should have said that I was amazed to see an **unexplained** close vote for such a nice question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof for $X = [0,1]$ (and $d$ the Euclidean metric).

Assume that $f$ is not surjective.

Notice that $d(0,1) = 1 = \text{diam}(X)$, and $d(x,y) < 1$ for all other pairs $x,y\in X$.

To satisfy the condition that $d(x,y) \leq d(f(x),f(y))$ for all $x,y \in X$, we must have that $d(f(0),f(1)) \geq d(0,1)$, so $d(f(0),f(1)) = 1$.

Therefore we must have that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$, or $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1) = 0$.

Further, we must have that $d(f(x),f(0)) = d(x,0)$ and $d(f(x),f(1)) = d(x,1)$ for all $x\in X$. Otherwise, either $d(f(x),f(0)) < d(x,0)$ or $d(f(x),f(1)) < d(x,1)$.

Consider that $f$ is not surjective, so there exists $y \in X$ such that $f(x) \neq y$ for all $x\in X$.

In particular, $f(y) \neq y$.

**Case 1:** $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$.

Then it is clear that $d(f(y),f(0)) \neq d(y,0)$ and $d(f(y),f(1)) \neq d(y,1)$.

**Case 2:** $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1) = 0$.

If $d(y,0) \neq d(f(y),0)$ and $d(y,1) \neq d(f(y),1)$, we are done.

So consider the case where $d(y,0) = d(f(y),0)$ and $d(y,1) = d(f(y),1)$. This means that $f(y) = 1 - y$. Then in order to have that $d(f(1-y),f(0)) = d(1-y,0)$ and $d(f(1-y),f(1)) = d(1-y,1)$, it must be the case that $f(1-y) = y$, but we know already that $f(1-y) \neq y$.

**Conclusion:** If $f$ is not surjective, then $d(x,y) \leq d(f(x),f(y))$ does not hold for all $x,y \in X$. Considering the contrapositive, if $d(x,y) \leq d(f(x),f(y))$ for all $x,y \in X$, then $f$ must be surjective.

I have a feeling this can be generalized for arbitrary compact metric spaces $X$ using $x,y \in X$ where $d(x,y) = \text{diam}(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, I would say it is false. Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the metric (in (in polar coordinates) $d(x,y) = |\rho(x)-\rho(y)| + |\theta(x)-\theta(y)|$, where $\rho(x)$ and $\theta(x)$ are the polar coordinates of $x$. Then consider the function

$$
f(x) = g(\rho,\theta) = (1000 R(\rho), \theta)
$$

where $R(\rho)$ is the truncation of $\rho$ to two significant decimal digits. For instance, in scientific notation, $R(\pi)=0.31e02$ and $R(0.000123)=0.12e-03$. Then

$$
d(f(x),f(y)) = d(g(\rho(x),\theta(x)),g(\rho(y),\theta(y)))\\
= 1000|R(\rho(x))-R(\rho(y))| + |\theta(x)-\theta(y)|
$$

Now, it is easy to see that $d(f(x),f(y))\geq d(x,y)$. However, the image of $f$ does not contain any point whose distance from the origin is an irrational number, so it cannot be surjective.

Edit: I missed the "compact" in your question. However, we can just consider the closed ball of whatever radius $a$, and modify $f$ to

$$
f(x) = g(\rho,\theta) = (\min\{1000 R(\rho),a\}, \theta)
$$

Still, $f$ would miss all the points inside the ball whose distance from the origin is irrational.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed, and fixed with an edit.

Comment: Probably the other way inequality is correct.

Comment: @LandonCarter constant functions satisfy the opposite inequality, and they are surely not compact unless your set is one point.

Comment: How did you come up with this example?

Comment: Look at non-constant functions then!

Comment: I am having second thoughts about this example. But the idea is to build a function whose range contains only rationals.

Comment: @LandonCarter Take a closed ball centered at the origin in $\Bbb R^n$ and shrink its radius by a factor of 1/2--i.e. scale things by 1/2--then the image is a proper subset.

Comment: I was trying to recall one similar result where an inequality in reverse direction implies surjectivity in compact metric space. Oh, right! You need equality.

Comment: Let $\theta_0$ be the argument of $0$, that is $0 = (0, \theta_0)$ in polar coordinates. Then $(\frac 1n, \theta_0 + 1)$ does not have a convergent subsequence. So the space is not compact.

Comment: Uhm. But if the argument is always considered as $\mod 2\pi$, then it does have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you define $\theta$ (i.e. what branch of log you choose), it won't be continuous. This example is incorrect.

Comment: I agree that this metric is not continuous with respect to the Euclidean metric, but why is that relevant?

Comment: Your function $f$ does not satisfy the condition that $d(x,y) \leq d(f(x),f(y))$ for all $x,y \in X$.

Consider $X$ as the closed disk of radius $1$. Pick $x,y\in X$ such that $\theta (x) = \theta (y) = \theta$ for some fixed angle $\theta$, $\rho (x) = 0.5$, and $\rho (y) = 0.75$.

Then $d(x,y) = 0.25$.

See for yourself that $f(x) = f(y) = (1, \theta)$, so that $d(f(x),f(y)) = 0 < d(x,y)$.

Comment: Uh, you're right. I still believe the underlying idea would work though. with some modifications. In particular, I would have to modify the coefficient (not 1000) and the number of digits you retain, based on $\rho(x)$, to ensure that if $\rho(x)<1$, then $\rho(f(x))<1$. I have to work out the details, but I believe it's possible.

Comment: Nope, it can't be, this question was closed as a duplicate, and the statement was proven to be true.

Comment: Ok, then I give up. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.